# nested select in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I save user logins in a table that named loginstats, I want to retrieve last login of every users, I use these code but I meet some error, What is my mistake?

```
select *
from loginStats
where id in (
    select distinct username, MAX(id) as id
    from loginStats
    group by username)
```

Comment: What is "id" and how does it relate to "last login"?  And why are you doing a sub-select?  Perhaps you can explain (a) your schema and (b) what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from loginStats
where id in (
    select distinct MAX(id) as id
    from loginStats
    group by username)
```

You can't have multiple field outputs in your `IN` subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing  `id IN`, but are trying to compare it to multiple columns. Try this instead:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM LoginStats A
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT username, MAX(id) as id
            FROM loginStats
            GROUP BY username) B
ON A.username = B.username AND A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also do this like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        RANK() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY loginStats.username 
                    ORDER BY loginStats.id DESC
                ) AS iRank,
        loginStats.*
    FROM 
        loginStats
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.iRank=1
```

[Here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/28/60146.aspx) is some information how to use the `rank` function and how it is applied.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) is some information on msdn about the `rank` function.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) is some information about `cte` function and usage

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) is some information about `With` clause and how it is used

Hope it helps you understand

Comment: Thanks, But I don't now these functions and word keys RANK(), Partition By, CTE. If you have some source that I learn from it, introduce.

Comment: No problem. I just think that if you understand this function you can write better queries. Maybe a +1 for the help?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that in the IN clause only one column can be specified and you are specifying two: `username` and `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting two fields, where you should only return one.  This correlated subquery should work for you:

```
select *
from loginStats AS a
where id = (
    select MAX(id) as id
    from loginStats AS b
    where b.username = a.username)
```